# Is there a fiber bundle/espace-etale interpretation of sheaves on a Grothendieck site

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, etale-cohomology, grothendieck-topologies

Whenever I'm doing sheaf things and I have a construction that involves sheafifying, I find it convenient to think "the thing that has the same stalks but sections must be locally trivial sections to espace etale" - it's a nice way to think of/characterize sheafification, sections of sheaves, define pullbacks, etc.

Can we do the same thing on a general, reasonable site (e.g. etale, flat, etc), i.e. for say $\mathscr{F}$ a sheaf on a scheme $X$ on the etale site, can we form something like $\coprod \mathscr{F}_x$ as $x$ runs over geometric points, suitably "Grothendieck topologized" so that the Grothendieck continuous sections over $U \to X$ are precisely $\mathscr{F}(U \to X)$?

Comment: What is a "Grothendieck continuous" morphism? And what category is it supposed to be a morphism of?

Comment: I don't know, that's part of the question of what such a formulation would mean.

Comment: Ok. The problem is that Grothendieck topologies very specifically generalize the property of topological spaces that they produce a sheaf theory, and not that they produce a notion of continuous map.

Comment: See here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78681/etal%c3%a9-space-construction-for-presheaves-on-a-grothendieck-site/111293#111293